# Reference to a pointer error: Non-const lvalue reference "const * FooBarClass" cannot bind to a temporary

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants, lvalue

FooClass.h:

```
class FooClass {
    .
    .
    .
    private:
        World *myWorld;
        const Player *&player;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

FooClass.cpp:

```
FooClass::FooClass(..., World *w) : myWorld(w), player(w->getPlayer())
{
    .
    .
    .
}
```

This triggers the following error: `Non-const lvalue reference to type 'const Player *' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'Player *'`. Yet the lvalue of type `const Player *`, is clearly a const lvalue...

Comment: `const Player *` is a type, not an lvalue. Whatever `w->getPlayer()` returns is a `Player *`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we talk about `const` references, we mean that the type that it refers to is `const`.

```
const Player *&player;
```

This declaration is a reference. But is the type that it refers to `const`? No, it's not! It refers to a pointer, but the pointer is not `const`. It just happens that the pointer points at something that is `const`, but that doesn't make the pointer itself `const`.

To bind a reference to a temporary value, you need to make the reference `const`. So you would need this:

```
const Player * const &player;
```

However, I can't imagine why you would want this. Why do you need a reference to the temporary value returned by `getPlayer`? Surely you just want a copy of the pointer:

```
const Player* player;
```

Comment: If, for whatever reason, the Player in my World object were to change, I'd want the `player` member to reflect that change, so I would need a reference wouldn't I?

Comment: @acannon828 Nope! If you copy a pointer, the original pointer and the copy both contain the same address. That means they point at the same object. Regardless of how that object is modified, both pointers will see it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant if the Player in my World object were to change to a different Player object.

Comment: @acannon828 Okay, but then you'd be modifying the pointer that is internal to `World`. However, `getPlayer` is returning a copy of that pointer. So your reference would be referring to the copy of the pointer which wouldn't be modified if you change the `Player` object. Sounds like you actually want `getPlayer` to return a reference too and then to store a non-`const` reference to that returned pointer. However, references to pointers are always a bad smell (pointers themselves are already).

Comment: Yeah currently there's no way to externally modify the Player object but I'm just trying to think of all possible scenarios. So you would just use a copy of the pointer?

Comment: @acannon828 If you need to see when that pointer changes, then you need a reference to the pointer, like you tried. You just need to modify `getPlayer` so that it also returns a reference to the pointer. Otherwise you're just trying to take a reference to the copy that `getPlayer` returns, which is not what you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61121/discussion-between-acannon828-and-joseph-mansfield).

Answer (score 1):

Change this definition

```
private:
    World *myWorld;
    const Player *&player;
```

to

```
private:
    World *myWorld;
    const Player * const &player;
```

Here is an example

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A( const int *p ) : r( p ) {}
    const int * const &r;
};

int * foo()
{
    return new int( 10 );
}

int main() 
{

    A a( foo() );

    std::cout << *a.r << std::endl;

    delete a.r;
}
```

Comment: Now I'm getting the warning `Binding reference member 'player' to a temporary value`.

Comment: @acannon828 See my updated example. It seems you are returning a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: @acannon828 object pointed to by pointer w can be a local object. So the compiler issues the warning. I showed you example where operator new is used.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
const Player *&player;
```

you need

```
const Player * const &player;
               ^^^^^
```

to be able to bind a reference to a temporary value.

You are getting the warning

> Binding reference member 'player' to a temporary value

because apparently `w->getPlayer()` returns temporary.